# Stripping model pk and fields text from Django queryset json output

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

In a view of django, I want to output the queryset converted to json without the model, pk, and field text.

my view code:

```
s = serializers.serialize('json', Item.objects.get(id=actuators_id)])
o = s.strip("[]")
return HttpResponse(o, content_type="application/json")
```

What I get is this:

```
{"model": "actuators.acutatoritem", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Environment Heater", "order": 1, "controlid": "AAHE", "index": "1", "param1": "", "param2": "", "param3": "", "current_state": "unknown"}}
```

What I spend all day NOT getting is this:

```
{"name": "Environment Heater", "order": 1, "controlid": "AAHE", "index": "1", "param1": "", "param2": "", "param3": "", "current_state": "unknown"}
```

I can I strip the model, pk, and field text from my output????

Answer (score 1):

Use [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson) to convert the qs to a python dict {}

```
import simplejson
s = serializers.serialize('json', Item.objects.filter(id=actuators_id)])

js = simplejson.loads(s)
//select the key needed and return the response   
s = js[0]['fields']

return HttpResponse(str(s), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: OMG. I spent about 4 hours on this task. Thanks!